# Creating jar file - no main manifest atribute

Tags: java

I am trying to pack my app in the .jar file but I've encountered some problems.

So, I have two classes:

```
Serwer.class
Serwer$ObslugaKlientow.class
```

And I have created the .jar file with this command:

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt aplk.jar *.class
```

manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: Serwer
```

but when I try to run this I get an error:

```
no main manifest atribute, in aplk.jar
```

I have changed the MANIFEST.MF file inside the .jar to this (I've added the last line):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)

Main-Class: Serwer
```

but it still gives the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `Serwer` really in the default package? Did you try specifying the fully qualified class name?

Comment: And is your manifest in META-INF?

Comment: It is in default package

Comment: And yes. It is in META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Drop the "-m" option  - its only needed/used to include manifest information from an existing manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

After droping the "-m" option:

```
jar -cvf manifest.txt aplk.jar *.class
```

I get results:

```
aplk.jar : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: Serwer$ObslugaKlientow.class(in = 1379) (out= 815)(deflated 40%)
adding: Serwer.class(in = 1592) (out= 973)(deflated 38%)
```

And nothing is created